# Interfacing with the Commodore 64 Serial Port using Assembly

Tags: assembly, serial-port, 6502, c64, commodore

I'm struggling a bit to find relevant documentation on this subject when it comes to using just assembly. All I've found is either irrelevant or for BASIC.
My goal is to be able to send and receive strings from the C64 serial port, but I cannot find literally any documentation on kernal subroutines, instructions, or examples.

Comment: This is not a site for requesting documentation. Try the [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @sawdust Alright. Will do. Thanks.

Comment: The question has been [moved to Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27463/interfacing-with-the-commodore-64-iec-serial-port-using-assembly) by the author.